# How to deal with component reference variables and props in React 0.12+?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider this naive routing mechanism:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/login') {
    this.setState({handler: <LoginScreen someProp="someValue"/>});
  }
}

render() {
  return <div>
    {this.state.handler}
  </div>;
}
```

So far so good. But how does one override props — or more importantly, set a ref — on the child component?

`cloneWithProps()` no longer supports `ref`, and you're not allowed to use `createFactory()` in a JSX file. You're not allowed to use `createElement` in a JSX either:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (window.location.pathname === '/login') {
    this.setState({handler: LoginScreen});
  }
}

render() {
  var handler = React.createElement(this.state.handler, {ref: "foo"});
  return <div>{handler}</div>;
}
```

Is there some undocumented behaviour allowing you to do something with either a component class reference, or an instance of such, in a JSX file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can absolutely use createElement and createFactory in a JSX file.  The only thing to note is that the `<X/>` is essentially a createElement operator, so just like you can't do `<<X/>/>` you can't create an element and pass it to the operator.

What you're doing is completely fine.  As long as you store the component class or factory, and not the element (instance) you won't have any problems.

In 0.12+ JSX differentiates between lowercase and uppercase component names, so if you want to use a dynamic component in JSX just alias it to a PascalCase variable.

```
render() {
  var Handler = this.state.handler;

  return <div><Handler ref="foo" /></div>;
}
```

Due to other changes Handler could either be a component class or a tag name string, e.g. `'div'`.

Comment: I'm so sure I already tried that. Oh well, it worked. Thanks! It's a shame that JSX requires the capitalized name, though. It doesn't feel quite idiomatic.

Comment: @AlexanderStaubo Thank you so much for that tip! Also, any ideas on what could go wrong while pushing such different `React` class references in an `Array`? On a `console.log(myArray)` (where `myArray` has class references as `[A,B,A]`), on `console.log(myArray[i])`, it prints `A` three times, whereas if I do `console.log(myArray[i].displayName)`, it prints correctly. Any ideas about issues involved here?